# how to view the input value entered by the user- on click in console log

Tags: javascript, jquery

cant view input value given by user in console on button click.

```
  function submit(){ 
var n= document.getElementById('input_text').value; console.log(n); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the function on click, then only it will be visible

```js
function sub(){ 
var n= document.getElementById('name').value; console.log(n); 
}
```

```html
<form class="m-form" id="searchInfo">
<input id="name"  type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" /> 
<button type="button" id="submit" onclick="sub()">Click
<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i>
</button> 
</form>
```

Comment: I am using the input within the form and I can't view it in console after entering and clicking on search button

Comment: can you post the code. its hard to know the problem without it

Comment: <form class="m-form" id="searchInfo">
     <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" />
     <button type="button" onclick="submit()"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></button>
                    </form>

Comment: There's no reason to add parentheses in `onclick`, as it turns a function reference into a nasty `eval()`.